# Why didn't Five seem to age when he time traveled forward?

Tags: the-umbrella-academy

In the first episode of Umbrella Academy('[We Only See Each Other at Weddings and Funerals](https://umbrellaacademy.fandom.com/wiki/We_Only_See_Each_Other_at_Weddings_and_Funerals)'),Five comes back from the future using a 'temporal anomaly'.
In the process,it is shown that he is aged backwards,leaving him with the physical appearance that was exactly like when he left the Academy 
and traveled forward in time.
However,in the second episode('[Run Boy Run](https://umbrellaacademy.fandom.com/wiki/Run_Boy_Run)'), he does not age forward when he travels through the time towards the future.
If he ages backwards when he travels back to the past, then why doesn't he age forward when he travels forward to the future?
Was there any explanation given to this in the TV show(or in the comic)?

Comment: "People assume that time is a strict progression of cause to effect, but actually from a non-linear, non-subjective viewpoint, it's more like a big ball of wibbly-wobbly, timey-wimey stuff."

Comment: When does he time travel forward?

Comment: @Paul Interesting. But how come that answer my question?

Comment: @Acccumulation See episode 2('Run Boy Run') ;)

Comment: You already mentioned that you're talking about that episode. Looking through the synopsis you linked to, I didn't notice any mention of him going forward in time, but I could have missed it.

Comment: @evilMinion it doesn't, that's why it's a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @Acccumulation Did you watch the episode? Then you sure must have seen that.

Comment: I don't have eidetic memory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the explanation in the show for him being de-aged on his first arrival in "The Present" was that he had made a mistake in his calculations that resulted in his body being altered. All the time traveling after that, for the most part, was seemingly done "correctly" (he doesn't comment on making more mistakes and doesn't seem to be physically altered) so there was no further impact on him.

Comment: I thought that there was something in the show about him trying to get back to his youth, and the de-aging was supposed to riff off the double meaning. But looking over the show again I can't see any evidence to back this up apart from the miscalculation statement.

Comment: There is the conversation where he's commended for body swapping as a way to throw off pursuit, but he says it was an accident and he can't take credit for it. We also see many time travellers that do not suffer de-aging.

Comment: So you are saying that in episode 2 when he traveled forward in time, he was never meant to age forward at all?

Comment: From context it seems like the time travelers organization is aware of the phenomenon of aging/de-aging but it's not something they generally worry about (see how surprised Cha-cha and Hazel were) because it's basically a safety hazard that they've successfully circumvented. So no one ever intends to alter their age when time traveling. Possibly because Five uses an innate ability instead of a suitcase, he runs greater risk of dangers like age-alteration.

Comment: Further more when the time travelers offer to reverse Five's condition they don't opt to do it by more time traveling (nor does Five try that himself) but by building him an entirely new body. It seems to imply that aging by time travel is both dangerous and difficult to do intentionally.

Comment: Nice explanation. Thank you.